# How to display fxcop report Jenkins artefact in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, jenkins, fxcopcmd

I have a problem with displaying FXCop 10.0 report in Jenkins. FXCop result & FxCopReport.xsl are added as artefacts.

We call FXCop with /oXsl parameter to modify the reference to xsl and it looks like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="FxCopReport.xsl"?>
```

The report is correctly displayed in IE but in Firefox we get unformatted string. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used Violaions plugin it is great for FXCop & Stylecop reports visualisation. Additionally it gives statistics of violations in time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try the [HTML Publisher plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin)?